# MySQL show all but one properties in JSON

Tags: mysql, json

I have MySQL table let's call it `MyData` and columns `id` and JSON type `data` column contains json string:

```
{
  "name": "Some nice name",
  "address": {
    "city": "City"
  },
  "category": {
    "name": "Name"
  },
  "nextProp1": {
    "prop1": "val1"
  },
  "nextProp2": {
    "prop2": "val2"
  },
  "nextProp3": {
    "prop3": "val3"
  },
  "nextProp4": {
    "prop4": "val4"
  },
  "nextProp5": {
    "prop5": "val5"
  },
}
```

How can I select all properties but not "category" through MySQL ? I checked documentation but found just this expression `JSON_EXTRACT(json_doc, path[, path] ...)`. Is there available more short variant instead enumeration of each path like `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.selectAllButNotCategory') FROM MyData WHERE id = '1'` and as result:

```
{
  "name": "Some nice name",
  "address": {
    "city": "City"
  },
  "nextProp1": {
    "prop1": "val1"
  },
  "nextProp2": {
    "prop2": "val2"
  },
  "nextProp3": {
    "prop3": "val3"
  },
  "nextProp4": {
    "prop4": "val4"
  },
  "nextProp5": {
    "prop5": "val5"
  },
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any shortcut for this. You have to list all the properties you want. Just one more reason not to use the JSON datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON_REMOVE()` :

```
SELECT 
       JSON_REMOVE(data, '$."category"') as Result
  FROM tab
```

and the last comma needed to be removed.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f3a3d8d5e95eefcd02eeb6927a6ccf8d)</kbd>